# Sound quality with really high sampling rate, but really low bit depth with dithering?

Tags: sampling, bitdepth, dithering

This question is probably more for fun and theory, but how will the sound quality be, if you create a sound with really high sampling rate (like 192kHz) and really low bit depth (e.g. 3bit)?

Can you emulate 44.1kHz/16bit with 192kHz/3bit (+dithering)?

I can probably think this through and post an answer myself with, sound examples computed in MATLAB, but maybe someone has already done that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is a sorta information-theory theorem regarding this (called the Gerzon-Craven limit) that was published long ago by Michael Gerzon and Peter Craven back in the late 80s.  i can't get a direct link to the paper reference, but type in *"Optimal Noise Shaping and Dither of Digital Signals"* into the [AES Convention paper site](https://www.aes.org/publications/conventions/).  this paper is a quarter-century old.  i just discovered that i have a camera copy of that old AES preprint and can send it to you if you send me an email to *rbj@audioimagination.com* .

I also have a copy of a paper making reference to the Gerzon-Craven limit [On psychoacoustic noise shaping for audio re-quantization](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1285808) .

There is an interesting title regarding this called [Approaching the Gerzon-Craven Noise Shaping Limit Using Semi-Infinite Programming Techniques](https://kclpure.kcl.ac.uk/portal/en/publications/approaching-the-gerzoncraven-noise-shaping-limit-using-semiinfinite-programming-techniques%285a02ceda-b564-4766-9924-0137ee367013%29.html). i don't have a copy of that and do not know how to get a free copy.

Essentially, because of the Shannon Channel Capacity theorem, the answer to your question is *"yes almost, theoretically"*, as long as you don't care about the magnitude of the quantization noise outside of your original 22.05 kHz baseband.  this is because the bit rate at 16-bit, 44.1 kHz is about the same (maybe just a teeny bit more) as the bit rate at 3-bit, 192 kHz and you can make an information-theory case that, because the information rate of the two cases are about the same, then the S/N ratio in the band of interest is also about the same.

But the real answer is *"no, practically"*, because of the difficulty in constructing a 3-bit noise-shaped modulator with such extreme specs and that remains stable.  with a higher sampling rate than 192 kHz, the specs get less extreme.

If you have a working system (what's it coded in, MATLAB?), i would be interested in your noise-shaped modulator.  what order it is and how well it behaves.  sometimes these nasty high-order ΣΔ modulators behave badly in the presence of *silence* and we get, what are called, *"idle tones"*.  if you think you have a working solution, i would be interested in hearing how it works for very low-level input.

Comment: Ha, no I don't have a working solution of it in MATLAB. I just thought about it quite naively :)

Comment: well, i can also send a sorta little MATLAB program that does ΣΔ conversion to 1 bit without changing the sample rate.  it uses a cheap, but always stable, 2nd-order feedback network in the modulator loop.  it can be modified to be 3 bits.  so you would first have to take your 44.1 kHz sound file and, using a standard sample-rate conversion utility (i think it's called *"resample()"* in MATLAB), upsample it to 192 kHz, and **then** pass that through your 3-bit ΣΔ modulator where the quantizer zeroes all but the most-significant 3 bits of the word.  then listen to that sound file.

Comment: Yeah, you can send me that, my email is in my profile, thanks!